# How do I decompile a .sis file?

Tags: nokia

I need to be able to view and edit a .sis file. Can anyone suggest the right way to do this please?

Comment: did you try google?  Searching for ".sis decompiler" seemed to turn up some decent results (http://www.blogsdna.com/1744/instantly-unpack-edit-and-sign-sis-files-sis-sisx-with-freeware-siscontents.htm).  Just a google search, can't vouch for how good the program is...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you could indeed extract stuff, modify them and re-pack them. there are tools that can help on this, for example [SisContent](http://symbiandev.cdtools.net/) claims to be able to do so, thus you could use this app at least for viewving the SIS.

Anyhow, the problem there is then the signing. If the app requires capabilities that are ok with Self-signing (and is not having any auto start feature etc.) then you could make own Self-signing certificate, either with the makekeys included in the SDK, or using OpenSSL. With SisContent, there also appears to be [Self signing certificate included in it](http://symbiandev.cdtools.net/signing.html).

Anyhow note that following capabilities: ReadDeviceData, WriteDeviceData, PowerMgmt, ProtServ, SwEvent, SurroundingsDD, Trusted UI, CommDD, DiskAdmin, MultimediaDD, NetworkControl, CommDD, DiskAdmin, MultimediaDD and NetworkControl. Can not be used with self-signing, and as there is no ways on signing apps (and there were never a way on signing others apps) with real Symbian certificate having publicer ID. and thus these apps can not really be installed after they are modified.

Then again, if you are targeting for pre-3rd edition devices, then they are not requiring any signing, thus you could extract the files, modify them, and simply repack with makesis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called [unmakeSis](http://www.symbian-freak.com/downloads/sisunmaker.htm).